# ASP .NET Core 3.1 problem get access_token with Microsoft OAuth 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I can not get the access token while calling Microsoft authentication.
I call this method with sign-in button:

```
public ActionResult OauthRedirect()
{
   var redirectUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?" +
                     "&scope=Calendars.ReadWrite offline_access User.Read" +
                     "&response_type=code" +
                     "&response_mode=query" +
                     "&state=de-medewerker" +
                     "&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44344/Admin/oauth/callback" +
                     "&client_id=myClientID";
   return Redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

This is OAuthController:

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class OAuthController : Controller
{
    string tokensFile = "D:\\tokens.json";
    public ActionResult Callback(string code,string state, string error)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
        {
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
            RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest();

            restRequest.AddParameter("client_id", "MyClientID");
            restRequest.AddParameter("scope",  "Calendars.ReadWrite offline_access User.Read");
            restRequest.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "https://localhost:44344/Admin/oauth/callback");
            restRequest.AddParameter("code", code);
            restRequest.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
            restRequest.AddParameter("client_secret", "MyClientSecret");

            restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?");
            var response = restClient.Post(restRequest);

            if (response.StatusCode==System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(tokensFile, response.Content);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
    }
}
```

when I start the project I get a 183 KB HTML format string in 'response.Content' that saves in tokens.json file when I change the .json to .html, inside of file is this text:

"
We can't sign you in
Your browser is currently set to block cookies. You need to allow cookies to use this service.
Cookies are small text files stored on your computer that tell us when you're signed in. To learn how to allow cookies, check the online help in your web browser.
"

[cookiesdisabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud18c.png)

But I checked in my browser and the cookie is not disabled.

[The debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOrKi.png)

Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token API endpoint is https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token.

Please update your BaseUrl to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token instead of https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?

OAuthController:

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class OAuthController : Controller
{
    string tokensFile = "D:\\tokens.json";
    public ActionResult Callback(string code,string state, string error)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
        {
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
            RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest();

            restRequest.AddParameter("client_id", "MyClientID");
            restRequest.AddParameter("scope",  "Calendars.ReadWrite offline_access User.Read");
            restRequest.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "https://localhost:44344/Admin/oauth/callback");
            restRequest.AddParameter("code", code);
            restRequest.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
            restRequest.AddParameter("client_secret", "MyClientSecret");

            restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token");
            var response = restClient.Post(restRequest);

            if (response.StatusCode==System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(tokensFile, response.Content);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved my mistake about /oauth2/v2.0/token but still does not work. [New debug image](https://ibb.co/cgHgWVb). This is [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mahmood-ghaem/OutlookCalendar). Shall I do something in the startup file?

Comment: @MahmoodGhaemmaghami as the message shows the client secret you have given is invalid. Please verify once.

Comment: Thanks for your help and [great learning video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlaJNuOIC_9-xCapKiQ-T5TKVu8ZSLpQR)

Answer (score 0):

In the second step your POST should be to the token endpoint:

- /oauth2/v2.0/token

Also use this content-type header for the POST request. I suspect that you're sending the client secret as JSON and this is why Azure is not receiving it correctly:

```cs
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Your OAuth controller also needs to write a secure cookie before the redirect if it is going to return to the client like that. Using the [built-in OIDC support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895345/) may make this easier.

**BASE URL**

Worth checking also that you are using the correct base URL. My development account uses a tenant based URL:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/7f071fbc-8bf2-4e61-bb48-dabd8e2f5b5a/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: Thanks, I solved my mistake about /oauth2/v2.0/token and added `response.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`  but still does not work. [New debug image](https://ibb.co/cgHgWVb). This is [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mahmood-ghaem/OutlookCalendar)

Comment: Looks like you may be sending JSON - see my updated answer.

Comment: Please note that newbedev is a Stack Exchange scraper; don't link to it. Instead, google the text or title, and find the correct link to the network, instead of giving scrapers more traffic that they don't deserve.